# Ajax request can't intercept response in json format

Tags: javascript, ajax

My script using ajax. It sends request to the controller and get response in json format. But instead of take the result my alax script do nothing.

```
function sayOK(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/company/' + id + '/employees',
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('OK');
                }
            });
        }
```

In my browser I'm getting whole json file

```
[{"id":1,"hireDate":1398114000000,"resignDate":null},{"id":10,"hireDate":1398114000000,"resignDate":null}]
```

Any ideas how to fix function?

Comment: Are you saying that the `alert()` doesn't fire?

Comment: You can add an [error callback function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your AJAX request in order to get the possible error message / code. It might also be worth opening the developer console and look for any errors.

Comment: What do the response headers look like when you execute the URL in the browser? Is the return type JSON or text?

Comment: `Response headers: Content-Type:application/json`. I see in my browser this line `[{"id":1,"hireDate":1398114000000,"resignDate":null},{"id":10,"hireDate":1398114000000,"resignDate":null}]`.